# How can I evaluate a certain integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

Could anyone give me a hint How I solve this integral by mathematica 
my integral is

```
Integrate[
   phi[x] Log[phi[x]] + (1 - phi[x]) Log[1 - phi[x]] + 
     chi phi[x] (1 - phi[x]) + (1/2) phi'[x]^2, 
   {x, 12, 20}]
```

with the following definitions:

```
chi = 62/27; 
phi[x_] := x Log[x] + (1 - x) Log[1 - x] + chi x (1 - x)
```

Notice the `phi'[x]^2` derivatives is taken with respect to $x$.

Comment: how should Mathematica now what to do with it, if you dont give any information about your function `phi[x]`?

Comment: phi[x] is just a function ordinary function  , what is given that phi[0] = 9.2

Comment: But if you dont give any information on it, you wont get anything from Mathematica. Trivial example: `Integrate[phi[x], {x, 0, 1}]` wont give you anything. What are you looking for? What do you mean by "solve this integral"?n `phi[0]=9.2` does not help, you need the function over the complete interval of `x`. Besides, you are integrating from 12 to 20.

Comment: this is my function phi[x]= x Log[x] + (1 - x) Log[1 - x] + chi x (1 - x)

Comment: Try `NIntegrate`

Comment: ok i will they it

Comment: f[x_] = x Log[x] + (1 - x) Log[1 - x] + chi x (1 - x);
chi = 62/27;
f'[x];
NIntegrate[ x Log[x] + (1 - x) Log[1 - x] + chi x (1 - x) + (1/2) f'[x], {x, 12, 
  20}]  does not work gave me an erro

Comment: When you define a function use `:=`, that means `f[x_] := x Log[x] + (1 - x) Log[1 - x] + chi x (1 - x)`

Comment: still can't got my result ; its show me an imaginary number

Comment: Is there any reason that you are expecting a real result?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any any particular reason why the integral should be real.

```
chi = 62/27;
phi[x_] := x Log[x] + (1 - x) Log[1 - x] + chi x (1 - x)

integrand = 
  phi[x] Log[phi[x]] + (1 - phi[x]) Log[1 - phi[x]] + 
   chi phi[x] (1 - phi[x]) + (1/2) phi'[x]^2;

Plot[{Re[integrand], Im[integrand]}, {x, 12, 20}, 
PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image]

Mathematica seems to be unable to evaluate abalytically the indefinite integral (at least in reasonable time). And considering its complexity this sounds normal.

```
Integrate[integrand, x]
(* ∫(1/
     2 ((62 (1 - x))/27 - (62 x)/27 - Log[1 - x] + Log[x])^2 + 
    62/27 (1 - 62/27 (1 - x) x - (1 - x) Log[1 - x] - 
       x Log[x]) (62/27 (1 - x) x + (1 - x) Log[1 - x] + 
       x Log[x]) + (1 - 62/27 (1 - x) x - (1 - x) Log[1 - x] - 
       x Log[x]) Log[
      1 - 62/27 (1 - x) x - (1 - x) Log[1 - x] - 
       x Log[x]] + (62/27 (1 - x) x + (1 - x) Log[1 - x] + 
       x Log[x]) Log[
      62/27 (1 - x) x + (1 - x) Log[1 - x] + 
       x Log[x]]) \[DifferentialD]x *)

(Integrate[#, x] & /@ (Expand@integrand)) // Simplify
(* -(5333/1458) - (4030 x)/2187 - (4805 x^2)/2187 - (
 151838 x^3)/59049 + (119164 x^4)/19683 - (
 238328 x^5)/98415 + ∫Log[
    1 + 62/27 (-1 + x) x + (-1 + x) Log[1 - x] - 
     x Log[x]] \[DifferentialD]x - 
 62/27 ∫x Log[
      1 + 62/27 (-1 + x) x + (-1 + x) Log[1 - x] - 
       x Log[x]] \[DifferentialD]x + 
 62/27 ∫x^2 Log[
      1 + 62/27 (-1 + x) x + (-1 + x) Log[1 - x] - 
       x Log[x]] \[DifferentialD]x - ∫Log[1 - x] Log[
     1 + 62/27 (-1 + x) x + (-1 + x) Log[1 - x] - 
      x Log[x]] \[DifferentialD]x + ∫x Log[1 - x] Log[
     1 + 62/27 (-1 + x) x + (-1 + x) Log[1 - x] - 
      x Log[x]] \[DifferentialD]x - ∫x Log[x] Log[
     1 + 62/27 (-1 + x) x + (-1 + x) Log[1 - x] - 
      x Log[x]] \[DifferentialD]x + 
 62/27 ∫x Log[-(62/27) (-1 + x) x - (-1 + x) Log[1 - x] + 
       x Log[x]] \[DifferentialD]x - 
 62/27 ∫x^2 Log[-(62/27) (-1 + x) x - (-1 + x) Log[1 - x] + 
       x Log[x]] \[DifferentialD]x + ∫Log[
     1 - x] Log[-(62/27) (-1 + x) x - (-1 + x) Log[1 - x] + 
      x Log[x]] \[DifferentialD]x - ∫x Log[
     1 - x] Log[-(62/27) (-1 + x) x - (-1 + x) Log[1 - x] + 
      x Log[x]] \[DifferentialD]x + ∫x Log[
     x] Log[-(62/27) (-1 + x) x - (-1 + x) Log[1 - x] + 
      x Log[x]] \[DifferentialD]x + (482 Log[1 - x])/2187 + 
 124/81 x Log[1 - x] - 3286/729 x^2 Log[1 - x] + (
 15376 x^3 Log[1 - x])/2187 - 1922/729 x^4 Log[1 - x] + 
 43/162 Log[1 - x]^2 - 97/54 x Log[1 - x]^2 + 
 62/27 x^2 Log[1 - x]^2 - 62/81 x^3 Log[1 - x]^2 - 
 398/243 Log[-1 + x] + 248/81 x Log[x] - 62/81 x^2 Log[x] - (
 7688 x^3 Log[x])/2187 + 1922/729 x^4 Log[x] + 
 143/81 Log[1 - x] Log[x] - x Log[1 - x] Log[x] - 
 62/27 x^2 Log[1 - x] Log[x] + 124/81 x^3 Log[1 - x] Log[x] + 
 1/2 x Log[x]^2 - 62/81 x^3 Log[x]^2 + 143/81 PolyLog[2, x] *)
```

May be in a book like the classic one

[Irresistible Integrals: Symbolics, Analysis And Experiments In The Evaluation Of Integrals](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Irresistible-Integrals-Symbolics-Experiments-Evaluation/dp/0521796369/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1488196708&sr=8-1&keywords=boros%20integrals)

you can find ways to evaluate the integrals that rest unevaluated in the last output.

My expirience has shown that Mathematica can do virtually all indefinite intergals that can be done analytically.

In any case,

```
NIntegrate[
 phi[x] Log[phi[x]] + (1 - phi[x]) Log[1 - phi[x]] + 
  chi phi[x] (1 - phi[x]) + (1/2) phi'[x]^2, {x, 12, 20}]
(* -6.20008*10^6 - 997716. I *)
```

which looks quite normal to me.

Some other references

http://12000.org/index.htm

[Abramowitz and Stegun. Handbook of Mathematical Functions](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/toc.htm)

[https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/articles/integr/mier.pdf](http://Definite%20Integration%20in%20Mathematica%20V3.0)

You can post also in the forums below

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sci.math.symbolic

I don't know if the first one is still active.

Of course wait and other replies from more experienced users or more mathematically oriented than me.

Comment: You are welcome:-)!